LeetCode food rating problem: change made by one HashMap is not being picked up by another HashMap
This is for LeetCode  food rating problem
I have Food HashMap to hold the foods, and Cuisine Rate HashMap to hold the cuisine to all the Foods.
After the inital setup, it has ("sushi", "japanese", 8).
The it calls changeRating()  to update sushi.  Inside this method, I first updated ("sushi", "japanese", 16). But then nested updateHighestRated will add the duplicated same  ("sushi", "japanese", 16) again to Cuisine Rate HashMap. My thought is Cuisine Rate HashMap somehow has the old ("sushi", "japanese", 8) even after it is been updated to  ("sushi", "japanese", 16).
To test this, I have another changeRating("sushi", 16) call after above. This time Cuisine Rate HashMap doesn't add duplicated.
class Food{
    public String name;
    public String cuisine;
    public int rating;

    public Food(String name, String cuisine, int rating){
        this.name = name;
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    void setRating(int rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    int getRating(){
        return this.rating;
    }
    String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    String getCuisine(){
        return this.cuisine;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.cuisine + " " + this.name + " " + this.rating;
    }
}

public class FoodRatings {

    HashMap<String, Food> tFood; //name -> Food
    HashMap<String, TreeSet<Food>> tRate; //cuisine -> TreeSet<Food>

    public FoodRatings(String[] foods, String[] cuisines, int[] ratings) {

        tFood = new HashMap<String, Food>();
        tRate = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<Food>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < foods.length; i++){

            Food obj = new Food(foods[i], cuisines[i], ratings[i]);
            tFood.put(foods[i], obj);

            updateHighestRated(obj);
        }
    }
    public void changeRating(String name, int newRating) {
        Food obj = tFood.get(name);
        obj.setRating(newRating);

        updateHighestRated(obj);
    }

    public void updateHighestRated(Food obj){
        String cuisine = obj.cuisine;
        TreeSet<Food> tSet = tRate.get(cuisine);
        if(tSet == null){

            Comparator<Food> comp = Comparator.comparing(Food::getRating)
                    .reversed()
                    .thenComparing(Food::getName);
            tSet = new TreeSet<Food>(comp);
            tRate.put(cuisine, tSet);
        }
        boolean b = tSet.add(obj);                  //<------- problem here!
        if(b)
            System.out.println("added " + obj);
    }



    public String highestRated(String cuisine) {

        return tRate.get(cuisine).first().getName();
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String[] foods = {"kimchi", "miso", "sushi", "moussaka", "ramen", "bulgogi"};
            String[] cuisines = {"korean", "japanese", "japanese", "greek", "japanese", "korean"};
            int[] ratings = {9, 12, 8, 15, 14, 7};

            FoodRatings foodRatings = new FoodRatings(foods, cuisines, ratings);//("sushi", "japanese", 8)

            foodRatings.changeRating("sushi", 16);  // this doesn't work
            foodRatings.changeRating("sushi", 16);
            System.out.println(foodRatings.highestRated("japanese"));

            foodRatings.changeRating("ramen", 16);
            System.out.println(foodRatings.highestRated("japanese"));
        }

}

Why does it behave like this? Both Food HashMap and Cuisine Rate HashMap hold reference to same object. But the change made by Food HashMap is not been picked up by the Cuisine Rate HashMap.

It looks like you're expecting TreeSet to automatically recognize that ratings have changed, to reorder the TreeSet and also to know where to find elements when sorting by rating.  TreeSet can do neither of those.

TreeSet does not check for the same reference being added; it only uses the provided Comparator to determine where to insert the item. Since the Comparator returns 0 when comparing the same element with itself, it simply does not insert the item (no duplicates in a set), nor does it update the ordering of the original key. This is why you should generally not use mutable objects for Map keys and if you do, you should not change their fields.
To change the ordering, you can simply remove the element and add it back after assigning a new rating.

The problem occurs because you are changing the key of an element that has already been added to the TreeSet. Therefore, the tree can no longer find an element with a changed key and correctly maintain the sorted order of the elements. It is better to avoid changing the key. However, if you still want to change it, you must remove the element from the TreeSet before changing it key, and then add it again after changing.
